# Insert text to specific span from in specific case using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have in HTML, three input fields and one button.
beneath **each** input I have a span.
Every click on the button triggers a function in which colors the empty field in red,
How can I insert a text to the span beneath the input in case the empty field?

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="train.css">
</head>


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="firstName">
        <span ></span>

        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="lastName">
        <span ></span>

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="" id="email">
        <span></span>
    </div>



<button onclick="showError()"> Show</button>
    <script src="train.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function showError() {

    const firstNameEl = document.getElementById("firstName");
    const lastNameEl = document.getElementById("lastName");
    const emailEl = document.getElementById("email");
    
    let rowsAreFilled = true

    let arrayOfAllInfo = [firstNameEl, lastNameEl, emailEl]
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfAllInfo.length; i++) {
        if (arrayOfAllInfo[i].value === "") {
            arrayOfAllInfo[i].style.background = "red"
            rowsAreFilled = false  
        }
        else {
            arrayOfAllInfo[i].style.background = ""
        }
    }
    if (rowsAreFilled === true) {
        alert("first name: " + arrayOfAllInfo[0].value + "\n" + "last name: " + arrayOfAllInfo[1].value + "\n" + "email: " + arrayOfAllInfo[2].value)
    }
}
```

Comment: You actually don't need Javascript, you can put the required attribute on your inputs and the browser will literally do all this for you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required

Answer (score 1):

You can have the browser enforce required fields for you in a `<form>` element with the `required` attribute:

```html
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="train.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form class="container">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input required type="text" name="" id="firstName">

    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input required type="text" name="" id="lastName">

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input required type="email" name="" id="email">

    <button> Show</button>
  </form>
  <script src="train.js"></script>
</body>
```

You can style the :required and :invalid pseudo classes:

```css
input:required {
  placeholder: 'required';
  border: 2px solid black;
}
input:invalid:focus {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: #f004;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="train.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form class="container">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input required type="text" name="" id="firstName">

    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input required type="text" name="" id="lastName">

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input required type="email" name="" id="email">

    <button>Show</button>
  </form>
  <script src="train.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the answers above of the kind people didn't really answer the question, I asked how to add a text to the specific span by JavaScript in case of empty field..
Any, this is the answer I got to:

function showError() {

```
    const firstNameEl = document.getElementById("firstName");
    const lastNameEl = document.getElementById("lastName");
    const emailEl = document.getElementById("email");

    const errorOneSpan = document.getElementById("errorOne");
    const errorSecSpan = document.getElementById("errorSec");
    const errorthreeSpan = document.getElementById("errorthree");
    
    let rowsAreFilled = true
    let arrayOfSpans = [errorOneSpan, errorSecSpan, errorthreeSpan ]
    let arrayOfAllInfo = [firstNameEl, lastNameEl, emailEl]

    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfAllInfo.length; i++) {
        if (arrayOfAllInfo[i].value === "") {
            arrayOfAllInfo[i].style.background = "red"
            arrayOfSpans[i].innerText = "Error!"

            rowsAreFilled = false  
        }
        else {
            arrayOfAllInfo[i].style.background = ""
            arrayOfSpans[i].innerText = ""
        }
    }
    if (rowsAreFilled === true) {
        alert("first name: " + arrayOfAllInfo[0].value + "\n" + "last name: " + arrayOfAllInfo[1].value + "\n" + "email: " + arrayOfAllInfo[2].value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Lilach, good you found a solution that works for you. Just remember to try and solve problems with HTML, CSS and JS in that order. Avoid using JS for something HTML can do on it's own.